# Java - Trouble understanding opacity value - parsing 64 bit long to float and adding opacity

Tags: java, floating-point, opacity, long-integer

I'm trying to understand some code that is creating an opacity value from the original color value.

```
    long fillColorValue = fillColor != null ? Long.parseLong(fillColor) : 0;
    //Set opacity based on alpha
    long alpha = fillColorValue >> 24;
    float opacity = (alpha > 0 ? alpha / 255.0f : 1.0f);
    shape.setFillOpacity(opacity);
```

1. First the String color value is parsed to long.
2. Then the bits of that value are being moved 24 bits with a rightshift - why?

> long alpha = fillColorValue >> 24;

3. then the long is used to create a float seemingly representing an opacity value.

> float opacity = (alpha > 0 ? alpha / 255.0f : 1.0f);

It'd be great if I could have some clarity on this method of defining opacity - what's actually happening here?

The shape fill color is originally represented by a String value -1751607581.

Comment: You seem to have a good handle on the bit-shifting, which seems like the more difficult concept. Are you unfamiliar with the ternary operator (` x ? p : q `), or are you asking why zero is being treated specially)

Comment: Or maybe you are asking why a 64-bit `long` is used, shifting off 24 bits and apparently working with the remaining 40?

Comment: Do you know what color format is used? It can be assumed, that first 24 bit is RGB (8 bit per channel) and remaining 40 bit is alpha channel, but in such case the subsequent operations seems strange.

Comment: In order to retrieve the integer Alpha channel value from the fillColorValue you need to right shift bits by 24. Not really sure why fillColorValue and alpha variables are declared a long when int would have sufficed. In the code you supplied, a Ternary is used to handle the chance that the Alpha value might be 0. Odd though since an Alpha value of 0 would normally mean *full transparency* but in this case the Ternary is enforcing the fact that any value less than 1 would place opacity to completely opaque (1.0f). There would of course be good reason for this in many different situations.

Comment: Not being very familiar with alpha and int/long to float conversions the method didn't make much sense to me, and the intent behind the code wan't clear. as @DevilsHnd pointed out the ternary is weird, and in fact this was the issue... transparency was showing as completely white.

Answer (score 1):

If the color are represented on 32 bits, like your example seems to, it looks like it is encoded with an alpha channel and three color channels, each on eight bits (most probably ARGB).

Shifting `>> 24` thus eliminates the RGB components, and keep alpha channels in low bits.

But beware of signed arithmetic! if original string is negative number, then `fillColorValue` will be negative, and remain negative after arithmetic `>>` shift...

With the guard on `alpha > 0` the consequence is that all negative or null alpha values will be considered as opaque.

That means that there will be no `alpha` value between 128 and 255, thus no `opacity` value in the open interval ]0.5,1.0[.

That sounds weird. Maybe that's the true intention... Or maybe the color should have been interpreted unsigned when being printed to a string?

Or maybe there are 9 bits in alpha channel, but then it would be a very unusual format, and I don't see the point to waste half possible values for a encoding a single opacity value... It does not make good sense.